# how to cleanly use JS variables in an onclick function that are set in the page load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a functionality that I had running in the

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var variable_name_1 = localStorage.getItem('var_1');
    ...
}
```

and I would like to move the functionality such that it only runs when the user clicks a button, in here:

```
function maketempuser() {
...
}
```

I can get the function to call when I want. But the function utilizes tons of variables from the load function. Is there a clean way to "globalize" these variables? Or must I find some way to add all these variables in the html:

```
<button ... onclick='maketempuser(variable_name_1, variable_name_2, ...);' >
```

NOTE: the javascript will run the same file, I just don't want it to keep re-running every time the user reloads the page since there is an ajax mysql insert that occurs because this page is one in a line of pages that enables a user to register.

Comment: Make the click handler inside the load handler where the values are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not pollute the global scope with a lot of variables (which can be overridden by other apps), I recommend you create an object with an app specific name, maybe something like this

```
var myAppVar = {};
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  myAppVar.var_1 = localStorage.getItem('var_1');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define them in global scope:

```
var variable_name_1;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  variable_name_1 = localStorage.getItem('var_1');
  ...
}
```

This, however, is not a particularly healthy technique, since it's prone to name collisions. Best thing to do is have a custom object (`cO`, or with your initials, something unlikely to be used by anything else) and use it as a placeholder for all your custom vars:

```
var cS = {
  var_1:null // or some default value...
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  cS.var_1 = localStorage.getItem('var_1');
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why define them in the global scope at all? You're getting them from localStorage which is already global. Why not just get them from there when you need them in the handler?

Comment: @gforce301 i didnt make it clear in the example, but not all of the variables that I set in the page load are retrieved from local storage.

Comment: @Rorschach Hence why everyone is supposed to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since `localStorage` is already global just retrieve the values you need in your handler from there.

```
function maketempuser() {
    var variable_name_1 = localStorage.getItem('var_1');
}
```

No need to add anything extra to the global scope at all.